# How to check if a fixed element is inside it's original container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header that contains an element that is fixed at the top of the page , While scrolling that element is sticky at the top.

The html code :

```
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="logo">Logo</div>
         <div class="social-media">
             <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
             <div class="youtube">Youtube</div>
             <div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
         </div>
         <div class="sticky-container">
            <a class="sticky-element">Button</a>
         </div>
        </div>
   </div>
  <p>


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis efficitur elit. Aliquam pulvinar venenatis libero, ac sollicitudin est egestas eu. Morbi egestas lorem at semper pretium. Sed odio diam, suscipit eu felis eget, aliquet malesuada odio.
Phasellus laoreet est in orci bibendum, sed laoreet elit maximus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus sodales sed magna vel gravida. Sed rutrum venenatis orci, eu ullamcorper ligula sodales pellentesque. Nunc quis mattis tellus. Duis non urna in mi pretium
aliquet. Ut congue, lectus et feugiat laoreet, est urna luctus augue, eu dignissim quam turpis ac nunc. Donec egestas nulla feugiat orci tincidunt convallis. Donec facilisis scelerisque massa, ut rhoncus est sagittis sed. Praesent fermentum quis magna
a sagittis. Donec fermentum cursus urna. Integer sodales sagittis nisl pretium fermentum. Nunc neque felis, luctus sit amet hendrerit sed, malesuada vitae justo. Praesent et massa non turpis lobortis imperdiet. Pellentesque et orci ac augue accumsan
venenatis eget sit amet ante. Etiam sed finibus magna. Etiam ut gravida nisi. Nullam pellentesque massa quis lorem euismod, sit amet ultrices diam consectetur. Proin vestibulum erat auctor mattis rhoncus. Vestibulum pharetra a tortor laoreet scelerisque.
Nullam tristique, libero sed porttitor varius, tellus tortor accumsan lorem, vel semper sem neque at urna. Phasellus in dapibus lorem. Quisque at rutrum risus. Curabitur efficitur non nunc sed semper. Nullam diam sem, iaculis eu ultrices ut, sodales
at magna. Nam semper leo vel bibendum cursus. Nunc tincidunt velit at eleifend tempus. Cras neque nisl, venenatis et lectus ac, blandit laoreet justo. Etiam dignissim, mi vel iaculis scelerisque, arcu ipsum consequat quam, eget elementum libero felis
luctus ex. Cras dignissim eu ante ac dapibus. Etiam condimentum arcu sed est sollicitudin laoreet. Nulla id nulla elit. Sed congue non ligula at maximus. Integer efficitur pretium erat eget mattis. Suspendisse eleifend arcu id ante congue ornare.
Pellentesque fringilla eu sapien a lobortis. Vestibulum aliquam eu risus at suscipit. Phasellus id lectus id lacus laoreet lobortis. Donec dictum porta eros sed vehicula. Pellentesque interdum nisl non arcu consequat dapibus. Etiam aliquam, lacus
eu sollicitudin mattis, tellus ante pellentesque ex, viverra aliquet leo urna nec tortor. Nullam mauris erat, pulvinar at dolor vel, feugiat ultrices est. Integer maximus vulputate turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
eleifend sed nisi at tempus. Donec vulputate, odio vitae feugiat consectetur, sapien dui venenatis nunc, ac vestibulum lacus ligula a ante. Vivamus sit amet accumsan augue, vestibulum ullamcorper libero. Proin vel rutrum ligula. Nam in risus sed ipsum
sagittis imperdiet. Ut eu laoreet nisl, eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam vulputate felis sit amet orci mollis volutpat. Fusce non dui elit. Nullam posuere ultrices turpis a accumsan.
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is a live fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/30shhy3L/2

How to check if the element `.sticky-container` is inside the `.menu`?

Comment: What do you mean by "inside"? The `.sticky-container` will always be a child of `.menu` as long as nothing moves it to some other element. As far as document flow `position: fixed` remove the element from the "normal" document flow much like `float` does, so in that respect it was never truly "inside" any element.

Comment: @gforce301 , When the page is loaded or there is no scroll , The element is on the menu that has the grey background , I want to check if the element is inside the menu , I mean it's within the grey background , The whole element

Comment: The only way to do this is with some math. See Mackenzie's answer. An interesting thing, when testing that answer, is that the x,y position of the fixed element never changes on scroll. So you'll have to get the position of the `.menu` element and the `.sticky-container` and do the math to see if it is "inside the bounds"

Answer (score 0):

You can check the position of an element with this:

`element.getBoundingClientRect();`

Perhaps you could check the position of each and determine if they are "inside" by your standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLElement.getClientBoundingRect()`.

Here's a quick script to accomplish this:

```
let menuEl = document.querySelector(".menu");
let stickyEl = document.querySelector(".sticky-container");
let stickyBounds = stickyEl.getBoundingClientRect();

document.addEventListener("wheel", onScroll);
document.addEventListener("resize", onResize);

function onScroll(event) {
  // get menu dimension & bounds
  let menuBounds = menuEl.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (isContained(stickyBounds, menuBounds)){
    stickyEl.style.background = "#990";
  } else {
    stickyEl.style.background = "#900";
  }
}

function onResize() {
  stickyBounds = stickyEl.getBoundingClientRect();
}

function isContained(objBounds, containerBounds){
    return (
      objBounds.top < containerBounds.top + containerBounds.height && 
      objBounds.top + objBounds.height < containerBounds.bottom &&

      objBounds.left < containerBounds.left + containerBounds.width && 
      objBounds.left + objBounds.width < containerBounds.right
      );
}
```